# Does the async attribute block the page content?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is related to async attribute in script tag.

In the https://javascript.info/script-async-defer link, I can see "The page content shows up immediately: async doesn’t block it."

But as far I understand, if we use the async attribute, fetching the script will happen in parallel but executing the script will block HTML parsing. So obviously page content will be blocked by the async attribute.

Can someone clarify what goes wrong in my understanding? will async block the page content?

Comment: Yes and no, HTML parsing and display will continue.  The script may modify it when loaded.

Comment: @Strom As I read in most of the resources, the execution of the script will block HTML parsing. How parsing will continue? This is where I got stuck in.

Answer (score 0):

The async attribute is used to indicate to the browser that the script file can be executed asynchronously. The HTML parser does not need to pause at the point it reaches the script tag to fetch and execute, the execution can happen whenever the script becomes ready after being fetched in parallel with the document parsing.
[image]
This attribute is only available for externally located script files. When an external script has this attribute, the file can be downloaded while the HTML document is still parsing. Once it has been downloaded, the parsing is paused for the script to be executed.

summary: async stops the parsing **while script is being executed** but after script execution as you can see in picture, still load parsing

Comment: Good visual, The point that I was going to add was the parsing will usually/may be faster than the network delay. Hence the yes and no.